# Should the linked C question be removed from C++ tag wiki?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

During (yet another) question about sequence points and undefined behavior in C++ I was informed that the C++ tag-wiki contains a link to a question that deals with this topic (and should therefore be a valid duplicate) in C: [Why are these constructs (using ++) undefined behavior in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior-in-c) (though it is listed under the name "i++ + ++i and similar questions" in the wiki)

Now (with C++11 and C++17) the behavior can differ in some cases between C and C++, especially in one example listed in the question:

```
int x[2] = { 5, 8 }, y = 0;
x[y] = y ++; // No longer undefined behavior as of C++17
```

Since the difference between C and C++ in regard to sequence points and undefined behavior seems to grow ever larger, should this question be removed from the C++ tag-wiki?

Comment: Oh dear.  Consider trying to get consensus in the C++ chat room first.  Ought to be a good fight.

Comment: Removed? No.   Redirected to a C++ rather than C question? Yes.